# Delete all files with executable permission in a directory

Tags: shell, files

I am in need of deleting all `executable` files from a directory. My directory contains some **configuration** files and **executable** files, and I need to delete all `executable` files that I don't want.

For that I have wrote a command like this:

```
ls -lp | grep -v / | awk 'match($0,"-**x*x*x",a);{print  a[1]}'| \
awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm -f
```

Is there aother way to do this?

I tried with `find`. It will list all other sub directory files. I used `grep -v /`, to avoid sub-directories in the current folder.

Comment: FWIW: your `awk` approach breaks for filenames with spaces.  Use the `find` solution below.

Comment: With zsh, this would be as simple as `rm *(*)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `find` for this task:

```
find . -type f -executable
```

will show you the files that are executable by current user, recursively.

To limit the search to current directory only:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable
```

To remove:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -exec rm {} +
```

Or with GNU `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -delete
```

---

As a side note, if you want to find files executable by any user, not just the current user (set as regular execute permission bits):

```
find . -type f -perm /111
```

Comment: Got it!! great, I tried with find after some time, I stopped that one and started digging into awk!! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain rm {} + meaning in remove command?

Comment: @saravanakumar `exec rm {} +` is `find's `exec` predicate within which `rm` is being used to remove the file. `{} +` will be expanded to the files found by `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable`

Comment: and if you wanted to remove those files executables for everyone (instead of being executable only by the current user (eg `750` mode)) you'll use `-perm -111`

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Not quite, check my edits..

Comment: @heemayl using `-perm /111` matches those files where any executable bit is set ( `740` or `445` for example), but using `-perm -111` matches those file where all user, group and others have the executable bit set.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Thats correct and thats what i have said,  executable by anyone..

Comment: difference between AND and OR.   `/111` requires that it is executable by someone (owner OR group OR other can execute it), `-111` requires that it is executable by everyone (owner, group, AND other).